# why is_standard_layout gives true here?

Tags: c++, stl, g++, clang++

my understanding is that not having any virtual method is one of requirements for standard layout. however, following code prints out true while there is a virtual method in struct Cancel.

if I remove the virtual method. is_stand_layout returns false which makes sense, as Cancel has members with different access control.

I tested this on gcc 10.2, 9.2 9.3 and clang 11.0, the results are the same.

is this a bug? or is there something I am missing about standard layout?

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

struct NewOrder
{
    int i;
};
struct Cancel
{
    virtual ~Cancel() {}
    int j;
private:
    int i;
}; 
int main() {
  std::cout << std::is_standard_layout_v<std::variant<NewOrder, Cancel>> << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't check if `Cancel` is standard layout or not, you check if `std::variant<NewOrder, Cancel>` is. That's a completely different and unrelated type.

Comment: `std::variant`'s internals are going to look like `std::aligned_storage<std::max({std::sizeof(Ts)...})> buffer; bool alternative;`  That's all standard layout.

Comment: @NathanOliver , if I remove the virtual method. is_standard_layout will return false. so it's just the implementation of variant is really tricky?

Comment: ah, variant does have different implementations for structs that are or aren't trivially destructible. this makes perfect sense, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this a bug?

No.

> is there something I am missing

You're outputting `std::is_standard_layout_v<std::variant<NewOrder, Cancel>>` which determines whether `std::variant<NewOrder, Cancel>` is standard layout rather than whether `Cancel` is standard layout.

> why is_standard_layout gives true here?

Whether `std::variant<NewOrder, Cancel>` is standard layout or not doesn't necessarily depend on whether the template type arguments are themselves standard layout. The standard doesn't specify whether `std::variant` is or isn't standard layout. The output that you see is a side-effect of how `std::variant` was implemented in the standard library that you used.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I thought variant is just a better union of multiple types. just so weird that it's implemented like this. having virtual function would make standard layout true, without it makes it not a standard layout.. also makes me wonder what is the usage of standard layout. I thought it means that it can be accessed in C. but I doubt how a structure like std::variant<NewOrder, Cancel> can be accessed in C.

Comment: I see that variant has different implementations for trivially destructible and non-trivially destructible template types.  it's like a direct union of new order and cancel when cancel is trivially destructible, and it's a union of different types when cancel is not trivially destructible. all this makes perfect sense now, great thanks.